# How to solve indentationerror

Tags: python, syntax

facing error like:

> Indentation Error: unintended does not match any outer indentation level,

```
run_id =id[0]
```

my code goes like this

```
else:

                    run_id = id[0]

                    runid_list.append(str(run_id))

                cur.execute("SELECT testcases.slug, WHERE result = 'failed' AND 
                runs.id=" + str(run_id) + "")

                for slug, reason in cur.fetchall():
```

Comment: Read about how python uses indentation for block delimiting here: 
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: I cannot see an indentation error in your post, but you post is incomplete. What's coming after the ``fetchall():`` and how is it indented? Are you sure the indention in the else block is in the code the same as you pasted it here? For the rest I think @jpp's link will help you.

Comment: The indentation error was evident before the editing. Check the not edited question

Comment: This should not have been edited then.

Comment: I added an edit reverting the changes in the code. Is there some markup to make the whitespace visible?

Answer (score 1):

In python code structure indentation is foundamental.

In your code, the problem is that the `else` statement has 0 indents (0 tabs OR 0 spaces) while the following line (`run_id = id[0]`) has 2 indents (2 tabs OR 8 spaces).

Dedenting by 1 this line should solve the problem (remove 1 tab or 4 spaces). You will face the same problem with the following line (`runid_list.append(str(run_id))`).

Anyway, I'd suggest to have a deep look on how [indentation works](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) in Python

Comment: The number of tabs after the else should not be a problem, as long as they are more than before. You are not limited to 1 tab or 4 spaces. But probably the code has spaces and tabs mixed (I cannot see this from the question).

Comment: you're right. Once you indent, you should mantain the same indentation level. Here the problem is because the first 2 lines have 2 tabs (or 8 spaces) and the next lines have 1 tab (or 4 spaces). The problem may also be solved indenting everything at 2tabs (8spaces)